# Is there an method to download the attached animated image from Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, styling, python-pptx

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re

data7 = data2[['Assessment Period', 'Practice 1 (Now)','Practice 2 (Now)','Practice 3 (Now)']]
    data7.columns= ['Assessment Period', 'Practice 1','Practice 2','Practice 3']
    #data7
data8 = data7.transpose()
data8 = data8.iloc[1:,]
data8.loc["Practice"] = round(data8.mean(),1)
data8.append(data8.mean().rename('Practice'))
data8.columns = ['Baseline','3 Month']
data8['Growth'] = (data8['3 Month']-data8['Baseline'])
# decimals = None
# data8['Growth'] = data8['Growth'].apply(lambda x: round(x, decimals))
data8

data11= pd.concat((data8,data10),axis =1)
data11['% Met'] = ((data11['3 Month']/data11['In 3 months'])*100)
decimals = None
data11['% Met'] = data11['% Met'].apply(lambda x: round(x, decimals))
#data11['Growth'] = data11['Growth'].astype(str) + '%'
data11['% Met'] = data11['% Met'].astype(str) + '%'
#data11 = data11.reindex([3,0,1,2])
data11



data12 = data3.groupby(['Assessment Period']).std()

data13 = pd.DataFrame(data12.to_records())

data14 = data13[['Assessment Period','Practice 1 (Now)','Practice 2 (Now)','Practice 3 (Now)']]
data14.columns= ['Assessment Period','Practice 1','Practice 2','Practice 3']
#data7
data15 = data14.transpose()
data15 = data15.iloc[1:,]
#data15.loc["Practice"] = round(data15.mean(),1)
#data15.append(data15.mean().rename('Practice'))
data15.columns = ['Baseline_std','3 Month_std']
#data15['Growth'] = (data15['3 Month']-data15['Baseline'])*10
#decimals = None
#datdata15a8['Growth'] = data15['Growth'].apply(lambda x: round(x, decimals))
#data15
data16=pd.concat((data11,data15),axis =1)
data16
```

`***Please have a look at image first:***

[Resulting PPT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEU07.png)

I have simple data of Practices and I can find all the metrics shown in the image , But I'm not getting 2 things :

1. How to generate dotted plots in my same image.
2. How can i download this image from Python and download it into my system with same formatting.

Can I reproduce same kind of image by Python script?

**Use Case: I need an Python script which can download the image from python in my local system so that i can just paste it into my PPT.**

I have tried the normal Python code and got this dataframe till now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94TUy.png)

Comment: If you need a Python script then you have to start to write one. Stack Overflow is not a free programming service but we will help if you get stuck on a specific problem *while* programming.

Comment: I'm not finding a way to do first point... Need help in that @KlausD., Edited though to show my dataframe generated till now.

Comment: *"I have tried the normal Python code"* Show us your recent code (as text, no images)!

Comment: Done... have a look @KlausD.